# API APP + Authentication with AAD and Facebook + AllowAnonymous

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api2, azure-active-directory, azure-api-apps

I have created a **API app in Azure portal**. Then after I have configured Azure Active Directory and Facebook for Authentication/Authorization in Azure Portal (Portal -> My API APP -> Authentication / Authorization). Now my requirement is **some API should be Allow Anonymous** and **other APIs should ask for Authentication** either from Azure Active Directory or Facebook.

Same issues like my case: [Question-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31515199/azure-api-apps-with-allowanonymous) [Question-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25049073/azure-ad-allow-anonymous)

Please help !!

Comment: can you manually handle this in authorize attribute ? you can check for the methods where there is no auth token passed and may be have a list or flag to ensure that it is indeed the method that is ok to be anonymous.

Comment: Custom authorize attribute is there but How can I identify if I have already logged in though Facebook or AAD?

Comment: what happens when the method is decorated with [Allowanonymous] attribute?

Comment: That works but what if our method is not decorated with this. So in this case we need to do some Authorization against Facebook and AAD. But main question is how can I implement that?

Comment: in case of fb or AD you would have registered the app first and got the clientid etc and also configured your client application https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/app-service-api-dotnet-service-principal-auth/

Comment: I have analyzed the "app-service-api-dotnet-service-principal-auth" but in the given scenario, there is a Web App which consume the API app by passing bearer token. In my case there is nothing like Web App.

Comment: Which application consumes your api

Comment: I will request to API APP from IPhone app, Google app from browser itself. So I need to access some method that is AllowAnonymous then I can use it but if Its authorized then I need to either from FB or AAD.

Answer (score 1):

I think, your solution may benefit from using [other authentication broker service called Azure Active Directory B2C](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-setup-fb-app/). Basically, you configure the providers you want on the backend side, then integrate it into your application. Then, you are able to use mechanisms like policies, etc, in your app. For WebApp integration with AD B2C - [tutorial](https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-web-dotnet.md).
I would do that in your situation because i believe that it would be better to offload authentication boilerplating to the backend instead of doing a lot of custom things in the application.

Other way of doing that would be to use custom attribute that will add the capabilities to authenticate, cache user information, authentication context (regarding your question about how to detect if someone is logged in) etc.

Comment: First of all, Thanks for your response. I prefer to go with second option which is custom attribute. But my question is how to cache user information of logged in user. Suppose I have already logged in into my facebook/AAD account from my browser and Then I am requesting for my API app for the first time. So in this case, how can I have the logged in details in my Web API?

Comment: Ah. Beg my pardon. Looks like what you want is to implement (at least part of it) Single Sign-On here. It will involve some coding and testing, and it would be tough to cover that topic in the Q&A format. Please take a look at https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/introducing-single-sign-on-to-an-existing-asp.net-mvc-application/.

Comment: This articles helps me to explain how single sign-on works. Can you please elaborate it practically as I am not clear how to achieve Authentication + Allow Anonymous.

Comment: When you are logged into fb in your browser there would be a cookie set. Subsequently if you have registered and authorized other apps for fb then when you open that it would seamlessly authenticate and authorize you to that app. SSO. If you decorate your anon methods with the attribute allowanonymous no check will be done.

Comment: Yes, that is what i meant. Thanks, Aravind.